# Are there many fewer rational numbers than reals?

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

Today my professor asked me to figure out the probability of getting a rational number from $[0,1]$.
His answer was that the probability is $0$.
Why is this?

Comment: The technical answer is yes, there are many more reals than rationals.  The measure of the set [0,1] is 1, but the measure of the rationals in [0,1] is 0.

Comment: May I ask what kind of class this is?  There are various senses in which the rational numbers are few in relation to the real numbers although there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: Well, this lesson is called "Introduction to Computers".The professor is introducing the concepts of "information" to us  in a mathematical way.

Comment: Actually, there are exactly three more real numbers than rationals. </silly>

Comment: This question has gotten way more attention than it deserves check out http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1172936/66223 (not my answer) look at the detail - 4 votes. Seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability measure in your problem is just a special type of measure. Any concrete single number has probability zero because as a set, it is a set of zero measure. Measure of all rationals in $[0,1]$ is also $0$ ([see this question for explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889633/measure-of-set-of-rational-numbers)), and so the probability of getting rational number is $0$.

Answer (score 57):

Intuitively, think that the rational numbers have a periodic decimal representation. If you draw a number digit by digit, what are your chances to make a periodic drawing compared to a completely random one ?

Comment: Really good, expressive explanation. Chapeau!

Comment: @GDumphart: I was the first astonished ;-)

Comment: Depends on what kind of universe you're in.

Comment: http://youtu.be/Swm8tTLWirU

Comment: I take issue with this intuition because what are the chances, really?  Any given pattern has a 0% chance to be made, but at any given time there are an infinite number of possible rational patterns you could generate. 0 times infinity = ???

Comment: @FooBar Yes, that's brilliant - [Vi Hart: Transcendental Darts -   Exactly 0% of numbers are rational.](http://youtu.be/Swm8tTLWirU)  (same link with title)

Comment: However regardless of what digits you have drawn so far, it always remains possible that the rest of the digits come out to form a rational number. Because of that I think your approach is not perfectly intuitive. But of course what you are saying is still true.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You can break one periodicity. But there is an infinite number of possibilities on how to create a new one. Regardless of how many digits you have drawn so far, there is an infinite set of rational numbers starting with that exact sequence.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's not an argument, it's a vague intuition. What your critics are saying is that they disagree that that intuition is convincing.

Comment: As JackM is saying, it is a vague intuition on the level of "There are more reals than rationals, that's why." As kasperd points out, for any non periodic finite sequence, there is an infinite periodic sequence with a period of the finite sequence. So for me, when I think of drawing a number digit by digit, it does not seem entirely intuitive that I am more likely to get non-periodic number as I will never know (because I would have to draw all of its digits which will never happen as I am drawing an infinite sequence.)

Comment: I'd like to add a bit of mathematics to help the intuition: for every $n,k$, the probability of getting a decimal representation with period $n$ with repetition starting at $k$th decimal place is $p_{n,k}=0$ (at least to me this seems much more intuitively obvious), so the asked probability is bounded above by $\sum_n \sum_k p_{n,k} = 0$.

Comment: I had to downvote because I could equally validly post "no matter how far you write, it's the beginning of *some* period, so it has to be rational!" and it would be as "intuitive" and just happen to be wrong.

Comment: @djechlin here is another "intuitive" but incorrect example: As we work our way one int at a time toward infinity, we add a single integer but pass by an infinite number of rationals. The probability of getting an integer from each such subset (aka, from a bag including each rational + integer passed recently) is 0, yet the rationals are just as "countable" as the integers even though this "same 0 ratio" is maintained as we go up. Might then not the rat be just as countable as the irrat even if rats are "thin"? [Obviously, the rat/irrat case would have to involve "sufficient" thin-ning]

Answer (score 14):

At risk of over-complicating things, if you dig a little deeper you'll find that your professor defines "uniform distribution" to mean that for any subset $S$ of $[0,1]$, the so-called "probability of drawing a number in $S$" is the Lebesgue measure of the set $S$.

If you don't know the real definition, you can think of the Lebesgue measure of $S$ as being the area under the graph of the characteristic function of $S$, that is to say the function that takes value $1$ for elements in $S$ and $0$ elsewhere. It might be that your professor would state his definition in terms of lengths or integrals rather than Lebesgue measure as such, but it will amount to the same thing.

Now, it turns out that that rational numbers are countable, and that the Lebesgue measure of any countable set in the real numbers is $0$. Hence, the probability is $0$ directly from the way he defined his distribution in the first place.

You need a certain amount of mechanism to define Lebesgue measure formally and show that the measure of any countable set is $0$, but the general idea is as follows. Consider a countable sequence of points $a_i$. For any given small number $\epsilon > 0$, we can put an interval of size $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ around the first point $a_1$, an interval of size $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ around $a_2$, and in general size $\frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$ around $a_i$. The intervals overlap, but the sum of the lengths of all of them is $\epsilon$, so the measure of their union is no greater than $\epsilon$, which recall can be as small as we like. This means the set $\{a_i: i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ can be contained in as "short" a set of intervals as we like, which (once we make a suitable set of formal definitions) means it has measure $0$ and intuitively it means the set of rationals "has no length" in the reals, and occurs with probability $0$. The complement of the rationals, the set of irrational numbers, *cannot* be covered in arbitrarily small intervals this way, and doesn't have measure $0$ (in fact it has measure $1$, which is good news for people who want their probabilities to add up!)

There are plenty of probability distributions on $[0,1]$ that aren't continuous, and for which your professor's statement isn't true. I presume he means the continuous uniform distribution because that's always the distribution people mean when they don't bother to state it, but the property does hold for any continuous distribution, so he's not out of order to leave off the details.

Answer (score 14):

All of the answers here presume that your `[0, 1]` denotes a subset of the Real Numbers, but you said,

> Well, this lesson is called "Introduction to Computers"

Computers do not use Real Numbers.  If `[0, 1]` denotes the set of numbers that could be returned by a random number generator (procedure) in a computer program, then the probability of getting a rational result from it is 1.

*Every* floating-point number is rational.

Comment: *Not* every number produced by a computer is floating point, or an integer. It's easy to precisely represent *some* irrational numbers – e.g. numbers of the form $a + b\sqrt 2$ for rational $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @BenMillwood, Sure, you can always invent a special data type to represent the members of some _finite set_ containing irrational numbers, but a general-purpose data type that could exactly represent _any_ irrational number would be impossible.  It would be impossible even if the values were limited to an open interval on R.  The reason is simple:  That would be an infinite set, and a digital computer has only a finite number of possible states.

Comment: @JimLarge Same goes for integers and rational numbers. A ge eral-purpose data type that could exactly represent *any* integer or rational would be impossible.

Comment: @heinrich5991, true enough, but that doesn't contradict what I'm claiming, which is that a "general purpose" `real` data type can only represent rational values.  Ben Millwood's example _does_ have irrational values, but I'm arguing that it's not "general purpose" because its irrational values all are solutions to one narrowly defined family of equations.

Comment: [Logarithmic representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_number_system) might reasonably include a large number of irrationals in their set of representable numbers. They're not very popular, but they're not entirely dead.

Comment: @JimLarge: there are several rather more "general-purpose" options.  The *algebraic* numbers are a well-known subfield of the reals that can be, and has been, implemented.  If you want more still, there are the *computable* or *provably computable reals; google "exact real arithmetic" for more on the options.  These aren't widely used for now, since they're very inefficient compared to the floating point options, but they certainly exist and are actively studied.

Comment: @JimLarge Many issues are being conflated here. 1) Real machines are finite, but many programs are written for unbounded machines, legitimising their study by CS. 2) Datatypes like `Nat = 1 + Nat` have infinitely-many values, and co-inductive types like `BitStream = 2 * BitStream` have infinitely-many infinitely-long values. 3) irrational and even transcendental numbers can be computed (abstractly) (eg. http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf ). 4) We can *represent* (as datatypes) more than we can *compute* (using a Turing Machine), ie. type inhabitation is undecidable.

Comment: There are many subtleties about *which* irrational numbers can be represented in computer programs, but this much is certainly true: you *can* represent $\sqrt 2$ in computer programs, and therefore a computer's random number generator *may* return an irrational number, and therefore this answer, in claiming "the probability of getting a rational result from it is 1", is mistaken.

Comment: @BenMillwood, OK, yes, if somebody wrote a random number generator that returned values in your $a+b\sqrt{2}$ system, then yes, some of the values would represent irrational numbers.  I think that several of the above comments have already demonstrated the limits of my imagination when I _assumed_ that a random number generator returning numbers $r\in[0,1]$ would return floating point values.

Answer (score 5):

There are only [countably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) many rational numbers in $[0,1]$, while the set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 4):

The probability that we choose a rational number should clearly equal the probability of choosing an $x$ such that $x+\sqrt{2}$ is rational - shifting the rationals by a constant certainly shouldn't affect probability. So, if the probability of picking a rational is $p$, then the probability of picking an $x$ such that either $x$ or $x+\sqrt{2}$ is rational must be $2p$, as those two events are disjoint. This means $2p\leq 1$, as every probability is less than $1$. So $p\leq \frac{1}2$.

However, this gives us trouble: the probability that $x+n\sqrt{2}$ is rational (for integer $n$) is *also* $p$. So, the probability that one of the following:
$$x,x+\sqrt{2},x+2\sqrt{n},\ldots,x+(n-1)\sqrt{2}$$
is rational must be $np$, as no two of those can be rational simultaneously (but, individually, would each be rational with probability $p$). So, we get that $np\leq 1$ any any $n$. Thus $p\leq \frac{1}n$ for all $n$ - which implies that $p$ must be $0$, as this is not true of any positive number.